# Is it possible to append arbitrary text to to a checkbox in SimpleForm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), I want to append a line of text to a checkbox. Is it possible to do this? I've tried, but so far no luck.

```
f.input :remember_me, label: "Remember me", # Would be nice if you could add 'append:' here
```

For example:

`Remember me [ ] Check this box to stay signed in.`

In this instance, "Remember me" would be the label, and "Check this box..." would be the arbitrary text I want to add. Is there a way to do this?

My expected html is this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not how to pass, or if you *can* pass, an additional param to SimpleForm helpers to include appended text.

Comment: It's the HTML I included. I clarified this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to have installed at least version 2.0.2 of the simple_form gem, and then:

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, :label => false, :inline_label => 'Remember me' %>
```

Comment: What version of simple_form are you using?

Comment: By the way, got this info from https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: That is it. A winner. Thanks. FYI: `as: :boolean` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, class: 'checkbox' do %>
  <%= check_box_tag :remember_me %>
  Remember me
<% end %>
```

Comment: While that does work, I'm looking for a way to do this within SimpleForm. It turns out there is another way address here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/424#issuecomment-4001247